# Toggle Shift on On Screen Keyboard

Tags: windows, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to select text using the on-screen keyboard, is there any way I can "lock" shift down so that I don't have to keep going back and selecting it?
Windows has two ways to do this:
1)By editing the registry to add shiftLock and then pressing the shift button twice on the physical keyboard
2) Pressing shift 5 times to enable sticky keys

Both of these options don't work on the onscreen keyboard, because you can't press shift fast enough.
Sending a "SENDKEYS" command will also not work, because its not pressing the actual key

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, what research have you done and what have you tried so far? Please EDIT your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about Windows (please be specific in your question) a quick web search brought this result: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-turn-on-or-off-shift-lock-for-touch-keyboard

> To turn on Shift Lock for Touch Keyboard in Windows 11/10, follow
> these steps:
>
> 1. Press Win+R to open the Run prompt.
> 2. Type regedit and press the Enter button.
> 3. Click on the Yes button.
> 4. Navigate to TabletTip\1.7 in HKCU.
> 5. Right-click on 1.7.
> 6. Select New > DWORD (32-bit) value.
> 7. Name it as EnableShiftLock.
> 8. Double-click on it to set the Value data as 1.
> 9. Click the OK button.
> 10. Restart the Windows Explorer process using Task Manager.

Once you've enabled Shift Lock, you can activate it the same way you used to on your physical keyboard: by double-pressing Shift.

Comment: yes, I have tried that, but pressing the on screen keyboard shift key does not enable this

Comment: Did you try that before asking, or just now? If you did this and/or other attempts, please list those in the question so that we know what not to suggest.

Comment: sorry, I did try that before and updated the question to show what I tried